# Obtener metadatos de una url

Tags: javascript

Actualmente necesito obtener los metadatos con javascript de una URL proporcionada , pero siempre tengo el problema de los CORS.

Con el siguiente código consigo leer los metadatos de la página propia pero me interesa poder obtener la información de una página externa.

```
<script>
function metaDatos() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + "Content of "+(i+1)+". meta tag: "+x[i].content+"<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Saludos !A ver si alguien me puede ayudar con el tema de las peticiones.. :)

Comment: no puedes solucionar el problema de CORS si la pagina que intentas leer no lo permita, no al menos desde el navegador. Pero si puedes hacerlo desde el server side por que CORS no se aplica ahi. ¿Estas abierto a una solucion server side?

Comment: CORS solo es para POST, deberias poder hacer un GET request a cualquier pagina. Estás seguro que ese es el problema? además, cuando haces una petición de AJAX el resultado es un string, no puedes encontrar las etiquetas META de esa forma, si no que te toca hacer operaciones de cadenas. Si lo que necesitas es como crawl unos sitios, es mejor que lo hagas desde el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usa un archivo PHP que lea la página que quieres escanear y así para evitar el CORS:

```
<?php

/* proxy.php */

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch  = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

A ese PHP haces tu llamada Ajax pasándole como parámetro la url que quieras:

```
<script>
    function getMetaDatos(url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'proxy.php?url='+url);
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = 4;
            var OK = 200;
            if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === OK) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    var html = document.createElement('html');
                    html.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    var x = html.getElementsByTagName('meta');
                    var txt = "";
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        txt = txt + "Content of "+(i+1)+". meta tag: "+x[i].content+"<br>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = txt;
                } else {
                    console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    getMetaDatos('http://www.google.es');
</script>
```